# Uploading files through the API

Tags: api, upload, files

I see an [older thread on the forum about potential improvements to the API to allow file uploads](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27122.0), but I'm not sure that ever happened. Has anyone ever uploaded files in CiviCRM using the API?

I see in the API Explorer that there is a **File > Create** with a parameter for **File Contents** but I'm not sure if you feed in the MIME contents, a URL, or...?

[image: File via API]

Comment: fantastic, that is good to know. does anyone know if we can provide an externalized attachment storage, example s3 buckets or firebase storage ? That is easier to scale than having it on the server running civi.

Comment: I think that warrants a question of its own. Also I don't know the answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it did happen and it's called the "attachment" api. You can look up the docs for it in the api explorer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And I confess my ignorance - does webform-civicrm use this so file uploads don't rely on the form submission not being deleted anymore?

Comment: It does for almost everything. The one exception is the "contact image_url" because Civi does not store an actual file in that field, just the url. So that currently is still only stored in the webform submission.

Answer (score 0):

Example to upload a image in custom field. Important, if you want to upload in custom field, you can't fill the `entity table`.

The field need to be of type file.

```
$fields = [
  'key' =>  $key,
  'api_key' => $api_key,
  'entity' => 'Attachment',
  'action' => 'create',
  'mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
  'name' => 'test.jpg',
  'content' => file_get_contents('test.jpg'),
  'entity_id' => 2, // Contact id, contribution_id,....
  'field_name' => 'custom_247' // Custom field type file
];
```