# CiviCase Attachment

Tags: civicase

1) I would like to know where the attachments for CiviCase are kept ? Can we configure it to use an external storage like Firebase storage.

2) How do you use the APIs to put the attachment as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Under admin - system settings - directories there is a setting for custom files directory. They are stored on disk in that folder. By default on drupal for example this is sites/default/files/civicrm/custom.

For the api see [Uploading files through the API](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12028/uploading-files-through-the-api)